# jQuery Accordion: divs with scrollbars not sliding nicely

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, accordion

I am using the following code to get an accordion happening:

```
$(".accordion h2").eq(2).addClass("active");
$(".accordion-content").eq(2).show();
$(".accordion h2").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".accordion-content").slideToggle("slow")
    .siblings("div:visible").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings("h2").removeClass("active");
});
$("div.accordion-content").hide();
$("h2#open").trigger('click');
```

However, when clicking the h2 to affect the accordion, if one of the "accordion-content" divs has a scrollbar (css set to overflow:auto), the divs seem to be overlapping and not animating nicely. Is there a way that I can set "overflow:auto" to happen only after the div is in full sight? Or any other way around this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the changestart and change event which are fired pre and post animation.
the ui.newContent should be the div in question.

Rough 2 second demo [here.](http://pastebin.me/a75980db839eae8a2db3c5fa3ea37e38)

```
$('.selector').accordion({
   changestart: function(event, ui) {
       ui.newContent.css('overflow' , 'hidden');
   },
   change: function(event, ui) { 
     ui.newContent.css('overflow' , 'auto');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks resquare. Though by the looks of your demo, your accordion is animating just as un-nicely as mine - there's overlapping going on in there...

Comment: Ah looked ok in chrome, which browser are you seeing the overlap?

Comment: That's the one! Any other solutions?

Comment: Avoid overflowing content. use a modal to show the extra content. You could try a direct message to the ui google group showing my demo and see if they can provide any ideas or a fix!